# mongoengine django and encoding, 'utf8' codec can't decode byte

Tags: python, django, mongodb, encoding, mongoengine

My mongodb use utf-8, and the django read data from it is not unicode, perhaps it is the answer,but how to solve this problem?

**the data in mongodb have some Chinese. If I use the other table totally of letters or numbers ,it will works well.**

```
class Source(Document) :
    id              = IntField()
    url             = StringField()
    fetchTime       = StringField()
    domain          = StringField()
    xml_tpl_old     = StringField()
    xml_tpl_new     = StringField()
    source          = BinaryField()
    xmlResult       = StringField()
    xmlResult1      = StringField()
```

if I use the table of source( it have some Chinese data )

```
Source.objects.all()
```

the django will give messages

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Django_project/mysite/mysite/test.py", line 49, in 
    unicode(Source.objects)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mongoengine-0.8.0rc4-py2.7.egg\mongoengine\queryset\queryset.py", line 216, in __repr__
    self._populate_cache()
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mongoengine-0.8.0rc4-py2.7.egg\mongoengine\queryset\queryset.py", line 167, in _populate_cache
    self._result_cache.append(self.next())
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mongoengine-0.8.0rc4-py2.7.egg\mongoengine\queryset\queryset.py", line 1148, in next
    raw_doc = self._cursor.next()
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo-2.5-py2.7-win32.egg\pymongo\cursor.py", line 814, in next
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo-2.5-py2.7-win32.egg\pymongo\cursor.py", line 763, in _refresh
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo-2.5-py2.7-win32.egg\pymongo\cursor.py", line 720, in __send_message
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo-2.5-py2.7-win32.egg\pymongo\helpers.py", line 106, in _unpack_response
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa1 in position 74: invalid start byte
```

Thanks!

Comment: 0xa1 is ¡ (U+00A1 INVERTED EXCLAMATION MARK) in Latin-1.

Answer (score -1):

try this in your python console

```
>>>import sys
>>>sys.getdefaultencoding()
```

if result is 'ascii',you should change the default encoding.

Answer (score -2):

I use base64 encoding before saving the data into DB.